# Resizable image To Fit a Label

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

Is there a way to make a image a stretchable to fit the length of label text from Xcode's Interface Builder? I try the slicer but I  and not able to make it stretch to fit the text , sorry I was not clear but this what I want to create

[image]

Comment: Try to constrains the imageView width and height equal to the label.

Comment: With constraints you should be able to do that, just match the width, height, centre y and centre x

Answer (score 0):

Add the width constraint equal with the label and to keep an aspect ratio on the image just add a ration one (1:1)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make the constraints of UILabel, UIImageView in the following way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using constraints just add:

[image]

You can change also the content mode of your image based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Set Label width and Image width as equal using constraints.